Kotlin is not configured in build.gradle but test cases exist for it checks. Can anyone help me to understand the rational behind it?
Description:
Error during ./gradlew build
During the Junit5 code build, the tests are failing. One of the test is "GradleKotlinExtensionsTests. gradle_wrapper()". Its error message is that Kotlin is not configured to use JDK. But when I go the build.gradle.  I do not see Kotlin or any configuration.


What is the rational behind having a test case to check Kotlin but by default it is not present in build.gradle?

I am missing anything?


    org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: result=Result
    {exitCode=1, timedOut=false, duration=PT14.0959783S, lines={err=[, FAILURE: Build failed with an exception., , 
    * What went wrong:, Execution failed for task ':compileTestKotlin'., > Kotlin could not find the required JDK tools in the Java installation. 
    Make sure Kotlin compilation is running on a JDK, not JRE., , * Try:, > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output., > 
    Run with --scan to get full insights., > Get more help at https://help.gradle.org., , * 
    Exception is:, org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':compileTestKotlin'., 

gradle.build file [Kotlin is not configured to use JDK]
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.nohttp)
    alias(libs.plugins.nexusPublish)
    id("junitbuild.base-conventions")
    id("junitbuild.build-metadata")
    id("junitbuild.dependency-update-check")
    id("junitbuild.jacoco-aggregation-conventions")
    id("junitbuild.temp-maven-repo")
}

description = "JUnit 5"

val license by extra(License(
    name = "Eclipse Public License v2.0",
    url = uri("https://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v20.html"),
    headerFile = layout.projectDirectory.file("gradle/config/spotless/eclipse-public-license-2.0.java")
))

val platformProjects by extra(listOf(
        projects.junitPlatformCommons,
        projects.junitPlatformConsole,
        projects.junitPlatformConsoleStandalone,
        projects.junitPlatformEngine,
        projects.junitPlatformJfr,
        projects.junitPlatformLauncher,
        projects.junitPlatformReporting,
        projects.junitPlatformRunner,
        projects.junitPlatformSuite,
        projects.junitPlatformSuiteApi,
        projects.junitPlatformSuiteCommons,
        projects.junitPlatformSuiteEngine,
        projects.junitPlatformTestkit
).map { it.dependencyProject })

val jupiterProjects by extra(listOf(
        projects.junitJupiter,
        projects.junitJupiterApi,
        projects.junitJupiterEngine,
        projects.junitJupiterMigrationsupport,
        projects.junitJupiterParams
).map { it.dependencyProject })

val vintageProjects by extra(listOf(
        projects.junitVintageEngine.dependencyProject
))

val mavenizedProjects by extra(platformProjects + jupiterProjects + vintageProjects)
val modularProjects by extra(mavenizedProjects - listOf(projects.junitPlatformConsoleStandalone.dependencyProject))

dependencies {
    modularProjects.forEach {
        jacocoAggregation(it)
    }
    jacocoAggregation(projects.documentation)
    jacocoAggregation(projects.platformTests)
}

nexusPublishing {
    packageGroup = "org.junit"
    repositories {
        sonatype()
    }
}

nohttp {
    source.exclude("**/.gradle/**", "gradle/plugins/**/build/**", "buildSrc/build/**")
}

tasks.checkstyleNohttp {
    notCompatibleWithConfigurationCache("https://github.com/spring-io/nohttp/issues/61")
}

